# "#pragma calls" and conditional compilation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, iar

I have an IAR project where parts are compiled depending on preprocessor symbols. For stack usage prediction, I need a `#pragma calls` directive listing the names of all functions potentially called through a function pointer, and it is an error to refer to a nonexistant function there.

Is there a way to pass the correct function list here, as `#pragma` and `#ifdef` are exclusive?

Comment: What do you mean with “`#pragma` and `#ifdef` are exclusive?”

Comment: I cannot use an `#ifdef` in the middle of a multiline `#pragma` with escaped newlines, so I cannot easily remove individual function names from the list.

Comment: Ah, I see. Does your compiler support `_Pragma` from C11?

Comment: Apparently it does, that might be the answer.

Comment: Does your system perform macro replacement on `#pragma` lines?  C permits, but does not require that.  If your system does perform such macro replacements, then you could use conditionals to help you define the function list as a macro, before the `#pragma`, and then just use the macro.

Comment: I suppose that "avoid pragmas like the plague" is not helpful advice at this point?

Comment: @JohnBollinger With `_Pragma` it isn't so bad anymore.

Comment: @FUZxxl, it's nearly as bad with `_Pragma` as without.  We hardly have to go past how a pragma "causes the implementation to behave in an
implementation-defined manner" (C2011, 6.10.6/1).  The issues solved by `_Pragma` are real, but secondary.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, how else (other than implementation-defined) should implementation-defined extensions behave?

Answer (score 1):

If `#pragma calls` expands macros in its arguments, one possibility is to define one macro for every set of functions you want to conditionally include:

```
#if CND1
#define CND1_FUNS fun1_1 fun1_2
#else
#define CND1_FUNS
#endif

#pragma calls CND1_FUNS
```

Another approach is to use `_Pragma` from C11 which isn't a preprocessing directive and thus doesn't interfere with `#ifdef`:

```
_Pragma ( "calls"
#ifdef CND1
"fun1_1 fun1_2"
#endif
)
```

Comment: Note that C does not require macros to be expanded in pragmas, though it *permits* it (with a couple of exceptions that are not relevant here).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Which is why I say “depending on how `#pragma calls` works.” Let me clarify this.